# indexing server in google chrome browser extension

Tags: google-chrome, solr, full-text-indexing, browser-extension

Is it possible to start an indexing server (like SOLR) within a google chrome extension, so that the user can index files to the local server via the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer I'm the author of the Google Chrome Extension [Solr Query Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/solr-query-debugger/gmpkeiamnmccifccnbfljffkcnacmmdl)

A Google Chrome extension is a Javascript program where you can make HTTP requests to your Solr server so that you can update and query Solr documents.

You can even upload your documents (files like MS Word, MS Excel, pdf, etc.) [with Solr Cell using Apache Tika](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika)

> Solr's `ExtractingRequestHandler` can use Tika to support uploading
>   binary files, including files in popular formats such as Word and PDF,
>   for data extraction and indexing.

So you have to configure  first `ExtractingRequestHandler` in order to upload your documents and then leave to Apache Tika the task to parse them.

Comment: I'm aware of Solr and it's features, but what I'm searching for isn't an extension to query a solr server. I want my extension to provide the server on a background page.

Comment: :) I was just trying to explain that you can. Because I did it.

Comment: I was also trying to suggest an integration with Apache Tika that would make your life easier.